# Azure App Service - CORS OAUTH2 error when accessing PWA webmanifest.json

Tags: html, azure, cors, progressive-web-apps, azure-web-app-service

I'd like to add PWA functionality to my App Service. It's written in C# ASP.NET. However, Chrome is unable to access the manifest and Edge don't even get the favicon (which might be a separate issue). Other desktop browsers apparently don't have PWA functionality yet.

Chrome is the only browser that requests the manifest. Here's the error message in my console:

```
Failed to load https://login.windows.net/b79fd714-9c54-449d-b377-3b59deb2d3b6/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%%{myappname}.azurewebsites.net%.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=67bedd5c-5478-44ec-ba13-85061c71114b&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=df52b6dc64dd4c3393957675f365ae93_20180903064438&state=redir%3D%252Fwebmanifest.json: Redirect from 'https://login.windows.net/b79fd714-9c54-449d-b377-3b59deb2d3b6/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%%{myappname}.azurewebsites.net%.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=67bedd5c-5478-44ec-ba13-85061c71114b&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=df52b6dc64dd4c3393957675f365ae93_20180903064438&state=redir%3D%252Fwebmanifest.json' to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/b79fd714-9c54-449d-b377-3b59deb2d3b6/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%%{myappname}.azurewebsites.net%.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=67bedd5c-5478-44ec-ba13-85061c71114b&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=df52b6dc64dd4c3393957675f365ae93_20180903064438&state=redir%3D%252Fwebmanifest.json' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://{myappname}.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**It would appear that my AAD authentication, which I enabled in the App Service, is interfering with my browser's manifest request.**

I understand that to resolve this issue quickly, Microsoft would have to add this application to their CORS. This is certainly not something I would expect to happen. However, I need some alternative way to let the browser access the manifest.

I have added the necessary mimeMaps to my `web.config`.

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  <remove fileExtension=".webmanifest" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

Here's the top part of my `Head`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/webmanifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="{myappname}">
    <meta name="application-name" content="{myappname}">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">


    <title>@ViewBag.Title - {myappname}</title>
```

If I was using some kind of AJAX request, I'd follow one of the [tutorials](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/09/receiving-cors-redirection-error-when-signing-into-app-service-using-azure-ad/) on the web. However, I have little to no control over the header, as far as I know.

Note: All occurrences of my app's name have been replaced with {myappname}. I really hope that those tokens are temporary...

---

In the tutorial link above, there's a relevant block of text that explains my issue better than my question itself:

> In a typical scenario after a user authenticates to Azure AD to log
>   into an application, Azure App Service sets a cookie called
>   “AppServiceAuthSession” for that authenticated session with the client
>   browser. The web application may use XMLHttpRequest / AJAX request for
>   various functionality of the application and the request sent to Azure
>   App Service would also contain the AppServiceAuthSession cookie. When
>   this cookie is not present in the request, Azure App Service will
>   redirect the request to Azure AD for login. This redirection causes
>   the AJAX request to become a CORS request since the destination domain
>   changes and Azure AD by default does not allow cross origin request.

In my case the browser is sending a request for the manifest that does not contain the necessary header.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm just winging it here, but you could try using the `crossOrigin` attribute on your manifest link like this:

```
 <link rel="manifest" href="/webmanifest.json" crossOrigin="use-credentials">
```

Here are some related links that might be helpful. According to the first page, user credentials are not passed by default when requesting the manifest.json:

- https://thatemil.com/blog/2018/02/21/pwa-basic-auth/
- https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/535
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes

Please let me know if it helps out.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I haven't personally run into this problem before, but I feel like it is just a matter of time... so I'll pack this knowledge away for later.

Comment: I ran into the same problem using Azure Web Apps with Authentication today. Thank you @TimHayes for providing this solution. This fixed the problem for me as well.

Comment: @MalteLantin - Good to know... thanks for the feedback.

Comment: For the record, if you're making a single page react app, you just need to add this to your index.html file.

Comment: same issue in an asp.net + react with azure ad login-in, worked like a charm.